# DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_21e2_0.MAI' (Errcode: 28), query was: DESCRIBE `sessions`

Tags: magento-1.9

please anyone help me to resolve this error on my Magento 1.9 website?

> DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write
> to file '/var/tmp/#sql_21e2_0.MAI' (Errcode: 28), query was: DESCRIBE
> `sessions`

[image]
My site is inaccessible.
please give me some suggestion on this issue.
or should I need to concern with hosting provider for this?

Comment: Once do verify if the server is not out of memory. That may be the case.

Comment: it is database overload issue?

Comment: yes also check if inodes are full you can verify it by executing "df -ih" command

Comment: @deepakd if ionodes are full so what can i do next?

Comment: You can delete files within var/report, var/logs or files from server log